# Create dictionary of dictionaries using list of labels

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary that labels a given dictionary that I have created. Basically, I have created a list that looks something like,

`labels = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]` .

I then have a list of dictionaries that look like,

`dicts = [{'to': 2, 'give':1}, {'you': 1,'an':1}, {'example' :1}]` .

What I'm trying to do is create a new dictionary that correctly labels each dictionary i.e. id1 goes with dictionary1, id2 to dictionary2 etc. Basically make a new dictionary looking like,

`new_dict = {"id1" : {'to': 2, 'give':1}, "id2" : {'you': 1,'an':1}, "id3" : {'example' :1}}`

I cannot get the notation correct and it's very frustrating. Does anyone have an easy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
result = {key: val for key, val in zip(labels, dicts)}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/yTHhrE)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @userpisquared Happy to help.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it as

```
labels = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
dicts = [{'to': 2, 'give':1}, {'you': 1,'an':1}, {'example' :1}]

new_dict = dict(zip(labels, dicts))
print(new_dict)
//{'id2': {'you': 1, 'an': 1}, 'id3': {'example': 1}, 'id1': {'to': 2, 'give': 1}}
```